# set datagrid pagination dynamically jquery easy ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-easyui

I'm using [jQuery EasyUI datagrid](http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/datagrid.php) to present some data to the user. By default the number of data that his displayed is 10. I would like to change this default to 30. I know I can do this when the datagrid is initialized by doing:

```
$('#my_datagrid').datagrid({pageSize: 30});
```

But for now I cannot do this on initialization because the datagrid is initialized elsewhere. Is there another way I can do this other than at the point where the datagrid is initialized?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Actually you could call this line at some point later and this will reload the grid data with the page size specified, so it doesn't have to be declared during the initialisation.

You could try placing the initialisation inside a javascript function (and call it inside $(document).ready) and then using a global variable to maintain the page size you wish:

pageSize: exists(selectedSize) ? selectedSize : defaultPageSize

where in the initialisation the size will take the default value (defaultPageSize =10) and afterwards the desired one (selectedSize = 30)